# PHP curl request return false

Tags: php, curl

This is my function:

```
function postCurl($url, $jsql) {
    $data = array('sql' => $jsql);//jsql is a json string
    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var_dump($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

It always returns `false`. I've tried to make the same request with REST client and it works.

Comment: curl_exec does return false if a error occurs. you can get the last errormessage using http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php.

Comment: after   `$output = curl_exec($ch);` add `if($output === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}`

Comment: I've checked the  `curl_error($ch)` output and the connection is refused

Answer (score 0):

Check in the server whether curl is enabled or not!!

and use the below code

```
$data = array('name' => $_REQUEST['name']);

            $ch = curl_init('www.example.com/');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $xml_output = htmlentities($response);
```